# Change value from in Parent Form from Child Form

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, events

I tried different solutions but had no luck... I don't know how to handle this. Following problem:

I have a main form (Form1) and a child form (splashScreen).

The code in my splashScreen:

```
    public splashScreen()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public splashScreen(Form1 frm1)
    {
        form1 = frm1;
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private static splashScreen m_instance = null;
    private static object m_instanceLock = new object();

    public static splashScreen GetInstance()
    {

        lock (m_instanceLock)
        {
            if (m_instance == null)
            {
                m_instance = new splashScreen();
            }
        }

        return m_instance;
    }
```

In my Form1 I'm creating a new thread and starting my splashScreen. The way I'm calling controls in my splashScreen is the following:

```
    splashScreen splashObj = splashScreen.GetInstance();

                if (splashObj.InvokeRequired)
                   {
                       splashObj.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate()
                       {
                           splashObj.Show();
                       }
                       );
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       splashObj.Show();
                   }
```

Now the splashScreen gets started when my Form1 is working and shows the current process. On the splashScreen I have a button "Cancel". When I click on that button I want to change a variable "killProc" - which is in my Form1- to "true" so that the work in Form1 can be stopped through a return statement when at some point "if(killProc)" returns true.

How do I change the variable in my Form1 through my splashScreen or is there even a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `GetInstance` method use the `splashScreen(Form1 frm1)` constructor to constructs an instance. They you have the reference to your parent from `SplashScreen`, which you could use the set property.

```
public static splashScreen GetInstance(Form1 frm1)
    {

        lock (m_instanceLock)
        {
            if (m_instance == null)
            {
                m_instance = new splashScreen(frm1);
            }
        }

        return m_instance;
    }
```

So, from `SplashScreen`

```
form1.killProc = true;
```

Comment: I get errors when I create the instances in my Form1. splashScreen splashObj = splashScreen.GetInstance(Form1 frm1);

Comment: Ok I tried splashScreen splashObj = splashScreen.GetInstance(this); Now it works fine! Thank you a lot!